# DSolve output displays different from actual output after using locator in Manipulate

Tags: differential-equations, front-end, dynamic

**V 13.2.1 on windows 10**

If you look at this

[image]

it does look bizzar, right? The same variable `sol` is different from what it should be above it.

But the above ONLY happens if I do this before

[image]

Below is the source code. What could be the explanation for this? Notice that I cleared `sol` also before using (even though not needed).

This happens only after using `Manipulate` earlier on.

It looks like because  Manipulate is still visible in the notebook, when typing `sol` in new cell, it is now using the `sol` in Manipulate instead of the `sol` variable just defined in the cell above?

*Is this the expected behaviour?*

I also include a link to the notebook itself at the bottom.

```
 Quit[]
Manipulate[
 sol = First@
   DSolve[{x'[t] == 5 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 2, y'[t] == 4 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 1,
      x[0] == p[[1]], y[0] == p[[2]]}, {x, y}, {t, -20, 50}];
 Grid[{{p},
   {ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, -20, 20}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PerformanceGoal -> "Performance", 
     PlotRange -> 5]
    }}], {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
    
ClearAll[x, y, t, sol];
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == 5 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 2, 
   y'[t] == 4 x[t] - 3 y[t] - 1, x[0] == -4, y[0] == 5}, {x[t], y[t]},
   t]

(*{{x[t] -> -(1/2) E^-t (-11 - 2 E^t + 21 E^(4 t)), 
  y[t] -> -E^-t (-11 - E^t + 7 E^(4 t))}}*)

 sol

 (* {x -> Function[{t}, 1], y -> Function[{t}, 1]} *)
```

Link to notebook is [here](https://12000.org/tmp/strange_mma_march_20_2023/notebook_strange.nb)

Comment: Put ``Echo["test"]`` before ``sol = ...`` inside ``Manipulate``. You will see that whenever something happens in the front-end (for example, a new output cell is created), body of ``Manipulate`` (being some sort of a dynamic module) is reevaluated, and ``sol`` is being set to ``{x -> Function[ ... ]}``. Even when you do ``Clear[sol]`` – it will first clear it, then it will immediately be set again by ``Manipulate``. Long story short: Don't use assignment to global symbols inside ``Manipulate``.

Comment: @Domen  That is what I suspected. I was just using code from another post with Manipulate which has `sol` as global and was trying solution again outside of Manipulate when I noticed this strange result.  Another Dynamic side-effect. but notice that `sol` itself is not Dynamic and that is why I thought it is strange that it will revaluate.

Comment: To correct my comment above: Reevaluation happens whenever you change `sol`. This indicates that `sol` is probably being tracked automatically by Mathematica. The usually recommended solution is to explicitly state which symbols to track, that is: Add  `TrackedSymbols :> {p}` to `Manipulate` which will prevent this unwanted behaviour you show above.

Comment: @Domen but isn't Manipulate has `LocalizedVariables` set to True by default? Here is a small example. `Manipulate[sol = x,
 {{x, 0, "x"}, 0, 10, 1}
 ]` and now in new cell, I type `sol=10` and then I type `sol` again in new cell, and its value remains `10` as expected. This is basically what I did. I know this behavior is related to using Manipulate in the cell above. But I am not still sure exactly why it happens, that is what my question is asking. I do not see why `sol` will change because I just typed in the variable name in new cell.

Comment: ``sol`` has to be used somewhere, like it is used in your ``ParametricPlot``. Try ``Manipulate[sol = x; sol, {{x, 0, "x"}, 0, 10, 1}]`` instead to see the effect. Also, ``LocalizedVariables`` affects only those symbols which are given as controls (which is only `p` in your case), not every symbol that occurs in the manipulated expression. See also [Advanced Dynamic Functionality | Automatic Updates of Dynamic Objects](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996).

Comment: `sol` is not a declared/control variable in `Manipulate`. So it is not localized. -- Re another comment: try `Manipulate[sol = x; sol; x, {{x, 0, "x"}, 0, 10, 1}]`. Then `sol = 10`, then `sol`.  In your test example, the body does not depend on `sol`, so a dynamic reevaluate is not generated by changing `sol`. In my test, the second `sol` makes the body depend on `sol` (simply because `sol` is evaluated -- but who knows what side effect that might have: retry my example with `sol /: Set[sol, foo_] := (Print["hi"]; sol := foo; sol)` outside `Manipulate`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the observed behaviour is due to `Manipulate` [automatically making](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996) `sol` a tracked symbol. When its value changes (or you use `Clear`), the body of `Manipulate` is reevaluated, and `sol` is being re-set.

You can observe this with a simpler example, which should be evaluated separately line-by-line:

```
Manipulate[sol = 5; sol, {x, 1}]
```

```
sol = 0;
```

```
sol
(* 5 *)
```

Convince yourself by listing all symbols that are being tracked:

```
Internal`GetTrackedSymbols[]
(* Hold[..., {sol, {154113}, False}, ...] *)
```

Symbol `sol` will not get automatically tracked (1) if it does not affect the output of `Manipulate`, or (2) if you explicitly set `TrackedSymbols`.

*You should delete the previous cell with `Manipulate` before evaluating examples below.*

```
Manipulate[sol = 5, {x, 1}]
```

```
sol = 0;
```

```
sol
(* 0 *)
```

---

```
Manipulate[sol = 5; sol, {x, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```

```
sol = 0;
```

```
sol
(* 0 *)
```