# Recording results of Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic

I'm studying the effects of some parameter on a complex system.
When we change the parameter, the system is converted and we need to write each new state to the list.
Problems encountered in using `Manipulate[]` for this purpose.
I've created a very simple model to explain:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n^p$$
Unfortunately the following program enters into infinite recursion (**Do not run this code!**)

```
Manipulate[
 newvar = var^p;
 AppendTo[trace, newvar];
 var = newvar,
 {{p, 0.5}, 0.1, 1., 0.1},
 Initialization :> {var = 0.5, trace = {}}]
```

I understand what's wrong, but I don't know how to get needed result.
`Do` or `Table` cannot be used, it must be interactive demonstration with manual change of parameter and recording of results.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your update. Why do you complicate with `q`? If you want a button to clean the list, just use [`Button`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) and show it inside `Manipulate`: `Manipulate[...; Row[{Button["Clean trace", trace = {}], var}, ...]`.

Comment: But this cleaning should be simultaneously with `q` changing!

Comment: Why avoid creating a new question? Seems better than having it closed for the **Needs more focus** reason ("This question currently includes multiple questions in one....").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should manually let Mathematica know that it should only track changes of symbol `p`. Otherwise, it will also track changes of `var`, and it will keep reevaluating the body of `Manipulate` indefinitely ...

```
Manipulate[newvar = var^p;
 AppendTo[trace, newvar];
 var = newvar, {{p, 0.5}, 0.1, 1., 0.1}, 
 Initialization :> {var = 0.5, trace = {}}, TrackedSymbols :> {p}]
```

Comment: AHA! I assumed that `TrackedSymbols` was only used for manipulator values, but now I realized that by default all variables inside are involved.
Thank you!!

Comment: @lesobrod, not necessarily all of them, just those that somehow effect the result :) You can read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/282581/75628) about a similar issue.

Comment: @
Domen
 Please note an additional question!