# Run Initialization in Manipulate Manually

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, dynamic

Although [I have received a lot of help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282874/recording-results-of-manipulate), there is a rather difficult question.
Let we have a system with parameter:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n^p$$
As long `p` changes, we have to write sequential results in an array.
But if you change `seed`, trace list should be cleared, and process should start with new value:

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[seed];
newvar = var^p;
 AppendTo[trace, newvar];
 var = newvar, 
{{p, 0.5}, 0.1, 1., 0.1}, 
{seed, 1, 100, 1},
 Initialization :> {var = RandomReal[], trace = {}}, 
TrackedSymbols :> {p,seed}]
```

To put it simply, when `seed` is changed, `Initialization` should start. But if `p` is changed, all should be going on continuously.
And I have no idea how to do it using `TrackedSymbols`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) on `seed`.

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[seed];
 newvar = var^p;
 AppendTo[trace, newvar];
 var = newvar,
 {{p, 0.5}, 0.1, 1., 0.1},
 {seed, 1, 100, 1, 
  TrackingFunction -> (seed = #; var = RandomReal[]; trace = {}; &)},
 Initialization :> {var = RandomReal[], trace = {}}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {p, seed}]
```

Comment: And another thanks! ))
Why there is no link to `TrackingFunction` in `TrackedSymbols` page? (